# Firebase CORS, whitelist IP ranges

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I need to whitelist two IP ranges to access my firebase cloud functions, how that can be achieved? I am pretty sure that should be a way to define them here:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
});
```

But couldn't find anything on Google with this syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the configuration docs for the npm `cors` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options), you can use an array as the `origin` value:

```javascript
origin: ["http://example1.com", /\.example2\.com$/]
```

Each element in the array can either be a `String` or a `RegExp`.

Or you can just use a single `RegExp` as the value:

```javascript
origin: /example\.com$/
```

> I need to whitelist two IP ranges

Since the values specified in the `origin` option are matched against the value of the `Origin` request header the browser sends, if the `Origin` values sent contain IP addresses instead of hostnames, then specifying an IP-address `RegExp` in the `origin` option should work.

But if the `Origin` values sent in requests instead contain hostnames, then you’ll need to either specify an array of hostname `String`s in the `Origin` value, or else a `RegExp` they’ll all match.